# Can't find chromium-flags.conf on raspbian

Tags: raspberry-pi, chromium, raspbian

Can anybody tell me were to find the *chromium-flags.conf-file* on Raspbain-Buster?

I've searched in *~/.config/chromium-flags.conf* but it isn't here.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In Raspberry Pi models purchased since mid-2019, the chromium flags defaults can often be found in:

```
/etc/chromium-browser/customizations/00-rpi-vars
```

However, you can overwrite the defaults by editing this file:

```
/etc/chromium-browser/default
```

Hopefully this helps anyone here!